# Limiting client usage with credits

Tags: php, angularjs, architecture

My web app is built with **Angular**, and **php** as an api server. I want to have a service which is limited by predefined time. For example a user gets 4 hours to run function `consume()` which consumes data from my server. This of course can't be handled client-side alone, because it will be bypassed.

What I'm currently thinking is some kind of credit system. for example, the user gets **240 credits**, and `consume()` pulls data from the api every 1 minute which costs **1 credit**. Is there a better way of doing it?

I couldn't find any hints about it on google because I don't even know what keywords to search for..

Comment: Do you want to limit user in time or the amount of calls?

Comment: Time. But it can't be continuous, can it? That's why I thought of dividing it into time sections (e.g. 1 minute)

Comment: May be better way to do is giving limit of API/Function calls.

Comment: Use $cookies to maintain each minute and at a particular interval save and update them with the db i.e. maintain the count as 240 in the db and update it after every 10minutes of user activity on that function like 230 after 10 minutes like you already suggested.